# How can I call a function in my HTML which is loaded using <script type="module">?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

index.html:

```
  <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunc()">click</button>
  </body>
  <script type="module">
    import Dog from './dog.js';
    let dog = new Dog();
    function myFunc(){
      dog.doSomething();
    }
  </script>
```

The script cant be called since i have type="module". If i dont have module I cant access the Dog class. How do I connect the html events with the modules?

Comment: Maybe of interest: [Loading a Modern Application with `<script type=module>`](https://matthewphillips.info/posts/loading-app-with-script-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind event handlers from JavaScript using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/addEventListener).

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", myFunct);
```

Don't use intrinsic event attributes.